# How to flash a firmware with J-Tag through Python?

Tags: python, jtag

I am currently using J-Flash-lite to flash a firmware (.hex file) on a microcontroller with a J-Tag connector.

Is there a way to use the J-Tag connector to erase or flash a firmware using a Python script?

After researches, I did not find this topic on the internet.